# Stieltjes measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Given a nowhere dense uncoutable compact subset $K$ in $\mathbb R$, can we find a Stieltjes measure $\mu$ such that $\mu(K)=1$, $\mu(\mathbb R\setminus K)=0$ and every single point in $K$ has measure zero?

This problem may have something to do with Cantor set. If $K$ is Cantor set, the Stieltjes measure induced by Cantor function will satisfy our requirement.

The problem is can we construct a monotonic right continuous function like Cantor function on any given nowhere dense uncountable compact set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To deal with the problem, you can refer to the construct of cantor function.To construct a nondecreasing right continuous function and thus leads to a measure. 
Thanks.